# How did I go off-by-one when prepending to a string in a loop?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a program to take a string; find and remove vowel in string, change capital letter to small letter and added "." before each letter. Here's the code:

```
input_string = "aBAcAba"
vowel = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
list = list(input_string.lower())

for letter in list:
    if letter in vowel:
        list.remove(letter)

result = ".".join(list)
print (result)
```

When I run this, I get:

> b.c.b

But the desired result is:

> .b.c.b

Why isn't `.` added before the first letter, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing in place, use a list comprehension to create a new list:

```
input_string = "aBAcAba"
vowel = {"a","e","i","o","u"}
new_string = ''.join(["."+i.lower() for i in input_string if i.lower() not in vowel])
```

Output:

```
'.b.c.b'
```

Also, changing `vowel` from a `list` to a `set` improves the overall lookup time.

Answer (score 1):

more simply

```
input_string = "aBAcAba"
vowel = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
list = list(input_string.lower())

for letter in list:
    if letter in vowel:
        list.remove(letter)

result = "."+".".join(list)
print (result)
```

Comment: the "join" command unites all the parameters in the list with the character that you provide to them

Answer (score 0):

```
result = ".".join(list)
```

will not add "." before each letter, but will result like you are getting. 
if you want "." in starting also you can add extra "."

```
result="."+".".join(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just neeed to print it, you can add the `'.'` on the fly when printing it like this:

```
print ('', *L, sep=".") # L being the list of remaining non-vowels
```

This will not create a string though as `print()` does not return the printed string. The other answers cover how to get the string already. I would still go for a list comprehension to create the partial list:

```
input_string = "aBAcAba"
vowel = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

L = [c.lower() for c in input_string if c not in vowel] 

print ('', *L, sep=".") # *L unpacks it to: print('','b','c','b', sep =".") for your data
```

The `*L` will unpack the list, the `''` before will add an empty string before it. By declaring a `sep="."` print will seperate each thing it prints by a `'.'`

Output:

```
.b.c.b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions to do that.

**Code:**

```
import re

input_string = "aBAcAba"
consonants = re.sub(r'[aeoiu]', '', input_string.lower())
result = f".{'.'.join(consonants)}"
```

I formatted the result using a Python 3.6+ feature called [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). I encourage you to find out more about it.

**Output:**

```
>>> result
'.b.c.b.'
```

`r'[aeoiuy]'` is a pattern that matches one of the vowels within the square brackets.

You can read more about regular expressions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) and use this [site](https://regex101.com/) to test if they match the string.

Comment: this will replace vowels by `.` - it does not work for `'klopaba'` (leads to `'kl.p.b.'`) as not every non-vowel is prefixed by a vowel. also your replace-pattern includes `y` which is not included in the questions list of vowels to be removed from the string (I am not the downvoter - just giving you a hint why you got dv...) I dislike downvotes w/o comments

Comment: You are right! ^^ I didn't read the whole question, my bad. I'll update my answer. He probably forgot about the `y`. As far as I know, it's a vowel :p

Comment: @Jatimir I'd 100% argue that it isn't ;p

Comment: not a vowel where I live - we even got Ä Ö Ü - and they aren't vowels either - or are they ...

Comment: "These letters are vowels in English: A, E, I, O, U, and sometimes Y." I wrongly assumed that it always is. Oops. However in my native language it is always a vowel :D

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = 'aBAcAba'
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
'.'+'.'.join([c for c in inp.lower() if c not in vowels])
```

Basically the last line does the trick, it converts input to lower case, check character by character if it's a vowel, finally joins the list to output a string. additional `'.'` is added at the beginning of the string.